# Getting checkbox tags (in a panel) to new form

Tags: c#, winforms

Rather new to C# so please forgive me if i am missing something simple or am trying to just do this the wrong way.

I am creating another form to compliment my main form and it needs to **pull some of the information from Main form on button click of Second form.** The information on the Main for is stored in checkboxes and textboxes.

I have the textboxes working fine but cannot figure out how to pull the checkboxes tag data over along with the formatting. Main Form  is working fine as is except I cannot figure out how to bring the checkbox data over as well.

This is the code i currently use to display the checkbox TAG data on my main form.

```
 //Statements to write checkboxes to stringbuilder
string checkBoxesLine = "\u2022 LIGHTS ";

foreach (Control control in pnlCheckBoxes.Controls)
{
    if (control is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;

        if (checkBox.Checked && checkBox.Tag is string)
        {
            string checkBoxId = (string)checkBox.Tag;
            checkBoxesLine += string.Format("{0}, ", checkBoxId);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the button i am using to open the new form and move the checkbox tag data and textbox.text data to the new form.

```
private void code_blue_link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    trouble_shooting = tshooting_text.Text;
    services_offered = services_offered_text.Text;
    other_notes = other_notes_text.Text;
    cust_modem = cust_modem_text.Text;
    //Opens CODE BLUE form and pushes text to it.
    code_blue_form CBForm = new code_blue_form();
    CBForm.cust_name_cb = cust_name_text.Text;
    CBForm.cust_cbr_cb = cust_callback_text.Text;
    CBForm.cust_wtn_cb = cust_btn_text.Text;
    CBForm.cust_notes_cb = cust_modem + "\r\n" + trouble_shooting + "\r\n" + services_offered + "\r\n" + other_notes;

    CBForm.Show();
}
```

Here is my code for the Second form and how i am getting the information to populate textboxes on that form.

```
public partial class code_blue_form : Form
{
    public string cust_name_cb;
    public string cust_wtn_cb;
    public string cust_cbr_cb;
    public string cust_notes_cb;
    public string cust_modem_cb;
    public code_blue_form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cb_name_text.Text = cust_name_cb;
        cb_wtn_text.Text = cust_wtn_cb;
        cb_cbr_text.Text = cust_cbr_cb;
        cb_notes_text.Text = cust_notes_cb;
    }
  }
}
```

Please forgive the long post! Any ideas/direction on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please shorten your question to the relevant parts of the code. Furthermore pls clarify what checkbox values (tag? format? checked prop?) you want to bring over to the new form.

Comment: Updated and shortened it some although i thought it would be important to show how i am using the checkboxes on my Main form. Also in the Op i did note i need to push the TAG value to the new form.  Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code (though the logic, and naming conventions are too bad) enough not to work as expected. But you seem to populate the control's in Form2 under button1 click event. Is that how you would expect? If you want the data to be displayed when Form2 loads, then move the code under button click handler to Form load event..

Comment: u are iterating thru controls (checkboxes) to get the data from main form, but you are not passing anything (I suppose `checkBoxesLine` to form2) !

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. Yes i was thinking of putting it in the load at some point. I know my naming is bad and working on it. My question was how can i get the checkbox TAG data over to the new form as i have not figured out how to push that over. The checkbox code above is the code of my Main form in which i push it to a textbox on that form. I want to push that same information to the new form on button click on the new form. Sorry if i was not clear!

Comment: I tried checkBoxesLine to form2 using CBForm.cust_lights_cb = (checkBoxesLine); but it gives me does not exist in current context

Comment: @Nabbic it's coz you dont have that in context. And your code is crying for some better logic. I will post an answer, with better handling. (by the way, tag ppl in your comments, only then they will get notification about ur comment, like this: "@xyz"

Comment: @nawfal Gotcha thanks! I am self taught (books, tutorials, websites) and is probably why i havent forced myself to use properNaming of things and following a set code logic. I am enrolled for classes this spring to hopefully set that right. This current project is something for my job i thought i would create to make note taking easier and re familiarize myself with Visual Studio. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to answer straight away using ur code. I find code smell. If I were you I would do this (but then if you are adamant about going with the same design, then you can tweak my code accordingly, no big deal, the bottom line is you get the idea how to do):

```
void code_blue_link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBoxIds = GetCheckBoxIds();

    cust_modem = cust_modem_text.Text;
    trouble_shooting = tshooting_text.Text;
    services_offered = services_offered_text.Text;
    other_notes = other_notes_text.Text;

    //take off underscore convetion and replace with camelCase convention.
    CodeBlueForm cbForm = new CodeBlueForm(checkBoxIds, cust_name_text.Text, 
                                           cust_callback_text.Text, 
                                           cust_btn_text.Text,
                                           cust_modem + "\r\n" + 
                                           trouble_shooting + "\r\n" + 
                                           services_offered + "\r\n" + 
                                           other_notes);

    cbForm.Show();
}

private List<int> GetCheckBoxIds()//even better naming required like GetFruitIds() 
{                                 //(whatever the id is of) or even better Tag  
                                  //checkBoxes with the Fruit object iself and not ids.
    List<int> checkBoxIds = new List<int>(); //So you can call GetFruits();
    foreach (Control control in pnlCheckBoxes.Controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;

            if (checkBox.Checked && checkBox.Tag is int) //tag them as ints. 
                checkBoxIds.Add((int)checkBox.Tag);      //I hope ids are integers.
        }
    }

    return checkBoxIds;
}

public partial class CodeBlueForm : Form
{
    List<int> checkBoxIds = new List<int>():
    string cust_cbr_cb; //should be private.
    string cust_name_cb;
    string cust_wtn_cb;
    string cust_notes_cb;
    string cust_modem_cb;

    public CodeBlueForm(List<int> ids, string cust_name_cb, string cust_wtn_cb, 
                        string cust_notes_cb, string cust_modem_cb)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.checkBoxIds = ids;
        this.cust_name_cb = cust_name_cb;
        this.cust_wtn_cb = cust_wtn_cb;
        this.cust_notes_cb = cust_notes_cb;
        this.cust_modem_cb = cust_modem_cb;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cb_name_text.Text = cust_name_cb; 
        cb_wtn_text.Text = cust_wtn_cb;
        cb_cbr_text.Text = cust_cbr_cb;
        cb_notes_text.Text = cust_notes_cb;

        string checkBoxesLine = "\u2022 LIGHTS ";        
        // if you dont require a lot of string formatting, then just:
        checkBoxesLine += string.Join(", ", checkBoxIds);

        // or go with your classical:
        //foreach (int id in checkBoxIds)
        //    checkBoxesLine += string.Format("{0}, ", checkBoxIds);

        //and do what u want with checkboxline here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tweaks. I will attempt to implement the code as you have written it here as it seems like a better was of going about it. There are definently some things there i do not fully understand but will be a good learning experience as i test each part to see how it works. One question where you say hope ids are ints are you meaning that the info in the checkboxes are integers? Because it is actually strings not sure what changes are needed for that `checkBox.Tag is string`  `checkBoxIds.Add((string)checkBox.Tag);` ?

Comment: @Nabbic if you are certainly tagging the checkboxes with string ids, then go ahead with what you have written in above comment. In that case you will have to return `List<string>` thats all. But I assume you id fields are just integers like 1,2 or 99. In that case its a better logic to Tag the controls with real ids. `Tag` property is of type object and can hold any variable. So its appropriate to tag the numbers as such. Like `checkbx1.Tag = 23` and not `checkbx1.Tag = "23"` or so.

Comment: If your are ids are not integers but strings like `fruit1`, then you should go ahead with string design. But in most cases they are are integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am implementing this now and also updating my naming on most of my stuff (Didn't realize how easy this was in the new visual studio it changes all references when you update one!)

Comment: @Nabbic glad I could be of any help. Yes VS is a beast and improves our work significantly..

Comment: Hello again! I got this implemented and working. I am curious however how it can be done on a button click instead (due to the way the program flows a button click is going to be needed) I tried bringing the code down into the button but it doesnt work obviously because it does not recognize the string within the button. How can i make it recognize the checkBoxesLines within a button click?

Comment: @Nabbic it can obviously be done. you have passed the necessary data to your form2, now when to display them is under ur discretion. To let you know, i have already answered it too partially. Find my edit.